# Ubuntu for Lenovo E531

Tags: preinstallation

A week ago I bought Lenovo E531 with Windows 8, but I don't like this operating system. I used to use Win XP. I downloaded Ubuntu 12.10, followed all the instruction how to create an bootable USB stick, but my laptop can't boot Ubuntu yet. Can You help me please!

Answer (score 1):

Since your laptop came with Windows 8, it probably has a feature called UEFI secure boot enabled, which can cause problems when installing Ubuntu.  Follow the instructions here to disable UEFI secure boot:

> 1. Create a LiveDVD or LiveUSB of Ubuntu (>=12.04.2) 64bit.
> 2. In your BIOS, disable QuickBoot/FastBoot and Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT). If you have Windows8, also disable FastStartup.
> 3. Boot your PC using the LiveDVD or LiveUSB and choose "Try Ubuntu". If you get a Secure boot or signature error, you may wish to disable SecureBoot as described here, then retry to boot the disk.
> 4. Install Ubuntu from the Live CD/DVD or Live USB in the usual manner, then reboot the PC.
> 5. If the PC does not load Ubuntu (but instead loads Windows, for example, as in Bug #1050940), or if the Windows entry in the GRUB 2 menu does not boot Windows (see Bug #1024383), boot your PC using the Live CD/DVD or Live USB and choose "Try Ubuntu" once again. When the live session has loaded, run Boot-Repair (see link for details). When Boot-Repair loads, click on the "Recommended repair" button, and write on a paper the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXXX/) that will appear. Then reboot the pc. Do not run Boot-Repair unless you have problems booting the computer; the expression "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" applies to this tool.

<sup>[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)</sup>

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Tim quote from article added.